# Ubuntu is creating empty folders in Home directory

Tags: home-directory

Sometimes Ubuntu create English version of my folders in home directory and these are empty. This is pretty annoying.

```
Desktop    Downloads  Muzyka    Pictures  Public     snap       Videos
Documents  Materialy  Nagrania  Pobrane   Publiczny  Szablony   Wideo
Dokumenty  Music      Obrazy    Projekty  Pulpit     Templates


==> /home/imiszczfun/.config/user-dirs.dirs <==
# This file is written by xdg-user-dirs-update
# If you want to change or add directories, just edit the line you're
# interested in. All local changes will be retained on the next run
# Format is XDG_xxx_DIR="$HOME/yyy", where yyy is a shell-escaped
# homedir-relative path, or XDG_xxx_DIR="/yyy", where /yyy is an
# absolute path. No other format is supported.
# 
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Pulpit"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Pobrane"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Szablony"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Publiczny"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Dokumenty"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/Muzyka"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Obrazy"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Wideo"

==> /home/imiszczfun/.config/user-dirs.locale <==
```

Photo of home directory:

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Which directories are being created, and when? FYI, can use a terminal to `ls ~` or `ls -la ~`, then copy & paste the text listings into the question (using the "code" formtting)

Comment: Desktop, Documents, Downloads, Music, Pictures, Public, Videos.
These are creating randomly. My language is set to Polish soo I also have: Pulpit, Dokumenty, Pobrane, Muzyka, Zdjecia, Publiczny, Filmy.

Comment: Add the output of `head -n-0 ~/.config/user-dirs.*` as well, please.

Comment: Okay. I added this to post.

Comment: The XDG... names look non-english, but the `~/.config/user-dirs.locale` file is empty?  No locale might have something to do with it... I don't know what your locale is though, `locale` in a terminal should output your settings, if they're something like `LANG='en_US...` that's english (FYI, lots of man pages about xdg... and user-dirs... stuff)

Comment: I have the same problem. My `locale` is set to `es_ES` on the `~/.config/user-dirs.locale`. However, for some reason, at some point, the default `/etc/xdg/user-dirs.default` is used instead of the user's file.

Answer (score 0):

Despite this will not solve your problem, may help you to find the root of it.

1. Use `ls -l ~ | grep Templates` to find the datetimem of the folder creation
2. Check the logs with `sudo grep -e "xdg" -R /var/log | grep -e "DATE OF CREATION" --color` for finding what was doing your system when the folder was created.

With this information, you may fix the problem or open a bug report on the application that is creating those empty default foders

Comment: I think snaps create them.

Comment: I just installed Firefox (snap) via Terminal to be sure and it created "Desktop" directory. I have elementary OS right now on my computer which don't have Desktop directory. I'm using English language now so it didn't create others.

Comment: I've open an issue in Snapcraft about this: https://github.com/snapcore/snapcraft/issues/2044

Comment: There is a pull request to fix this. See https://github.com/ubuntu/snapcraft-desktop-helpers/pull/103